# Eclipse gtkmm cross-compiling for Raspberry Pi, can't find file ft2build.h even though it does exist

Tags: linux, eclipse, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi, gtkmm

I am trying to cross-compile a C++ program for the Raspberry Pi using gtkmm in Eclipse under Linux (Ubuntu).  I initially set up the cross-compiler using the guide found [here](http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/), which worked perfectly.

When I then added `#include <gtkmm.h>` to a program, Eclipse could not find the library.  This was fixed by going to (project)Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings, then adding `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` to Cross G++ Compiler->Miscellaneous->Other flags, selecting verbose(-v) and adding `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` to Cross G++ Linker->Miscellaneous->Linker Flags. (Both flag additions are enclosed by `, not ', symbols in Eclipse though this doesn't show here.)

Now Eclipse gives the following error: `/usr/include/cairo/cairo-ft.h:46:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory`.  The file ft2build.h exists on my computer in `/usr/include`, but Eclipse cannot see it and I have had no luck searching for a solution. Any advice?

Thanks

UPDATE:  After a lot more searching, I disabled freetype fonts in the cairo library used by gtkmm.  This was done by commenting out `#define CAIRO_HAS_FT_FONT 1` in `cairo-features.h`.  The next problem was that Eclipse could not find the libraries used by gtkmm, so I added `\usr\libs` to (project)Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Library paths. After doing all this, it returns the following error when trying to build: `/usr/lib//libgtkmm-3.0.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized`.  This file format seems to be standard though, so what is going wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new project, set up for cross-compiling as before.  I then installed gtkmm on my Raspberry Pi, before copying the `/usr/` and `/lib/` folders from the Pi's SD card to my laptop.  Once this was done I went to (project)Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings. I then added all of the includes listed by `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags` to  Cross G++ Compiler->Includes, and all of the libraries listed by `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs` to  Cross G++ Linker->Libraries - BUT I changed the paths to point to the Pi's library files.

As before, I had to disable freetype fonts in cairo.  It still didn't build though, because the included libraries have others they depend on in turn. So the final step was to find and include all of the listed libraries in the Pi files I had copied over. The simple gtkmm example now builds in Eclipse and can be run on the Pi!